# How long is overtime?

Tags: overwatch

In Overwatch, if the attacking team is touching a payload or control point when the round timer runs out, the game will enter Overtime.

How long does Overtime last after the attacking team stops touching the objective?

Comment: Not enough to win, yet always enough to lose by a fraction of second.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, my answer is going to seem like speculation, because it truly is.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any patch notes or dev announcements from Blizzard that specify exactly what the Overtime length is.

The subreddit, and many posts on the official forums (which 404 for me now, so I won't provide any links) seem to agree that it is **~10 seconds**, and I can concur with that number from personal experience.

Example link from the subreddit expressing this belief: https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/3p0esi/there_doesnt_seem_to_be_much_info_on_the/

Comment: Nothing to back this up, I get the feeling from playing that overtime extends while both teams are still contesting the objective (attacker is touching the payload, but not at the destination, contesting the point, etc).

Comment: @JamesCW it resets once someone gets to the objective.

Comment: Based on an endgame video I have, around ten seconds.  The video shows a roughly five second gap with no attacker in the point and the fuse burned about half way down before reseting.

Comment: So there is a little leeway to get back on it - I am usually halfway back from spawn at that point : )

Comment: I've heard that the time gets tighter and tighter to avoid a tracer being able to keep overtime indefinitely

Comment: I've played a few games where the team gets two Tracers or a second Lucio to start ferrying more people from spawn faster. Multiple Tracers usually can keep overtime up indefinitely. I'm not sure if the time really does get tighter. @JamesCW, the question states "after the attacking team stops touching the objective," so that was implicit in my answer.

Comment: This video implies there are no real limits and that the burndown of the fuse stays roughly the same: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uu3usdnMtrY.  And here's another: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4tztwkru2E

Comment: @cottog good point!